# easy way to manage VMware ESXi on Mac OS X

Tags: snow-leopard, mac, vmware

I'm a VMware guy, running a dozen of ESXi ... and i'm also a mac user and I've had it with launching VMware Fusion to boot my Win7 to work on vSphere client...

Am I missing something? Sys Admins and Solution Architects are using Linux/Mac more and more ... Is there anyway that i can do that without having to rely on rdesktop and other unreliable workarounds?

Comment: The best answer is "sometimes." IF you're using vSphere 5.1 you can use the Web Client under OS-X. However, some operations only work with the vSphere desktop client, and other only work in the vSphere web client.   If you can wait, the web client will become the only way to go, so there's some light at the end of the tunnel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got access to vCenter, then you can administer your servers via the vCenter Web Access page. Otherwise, if you have any Windows VMs then you could install the vSphere client in there and remote-desktop into it as a standalone application.

Comment: That's just been officiated with vSphere 5.1

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X, no. The only Apple management option is the iPad management app that VMware released a short while ago.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if all you need is basic control from OSX, check out Orbit-VM https://code.google.com/p/orbit-vm/

> It's aim is to provide an open source, cross-platform GUI for managing vSphere 4 servers.

However, I use this to manange my ESXi 5 box and it works great on Mountain Lion!

Comment: It doesn't work with newer macOS versions (macOS Monterey).

Answer (score 1):

No need for esx client. Here's the ultra-unix-geek answer: ssh to esx host, run vim-cmd power.on , or any number of actions available for the vim-cmd.  ..sometimes they even work!  How's that for geeky.

Basically VMware is Windows now. They have the microsoft philosophy of 'dumbing down' everything. They been doing it with vmware for years. It used to be completely manageable by anyone with unix/linux skills. Now its an almost completely dumbed down - windoze-afied linux, with a completely crippled shell.

My advice: switch to KVM (RHEV for ex.), escape vmware vendor lock-in, save up to 40% on expenses, and have a real 'nix OS that you can manage. :)  Peace, out.

Answer (score -2):

vClient Mac APP @ [vclient.top](https://web.archive.org/web/20190905213550/http://vclient.top/) is native mac app to manage esx/vcenter

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: The website isn't available anymore. The vClient still can be downloaded at https://dl.devmate.com/com.wanshuhou.vclient/vClient.dmg but it's a trial software apparently not available for purchase anymore.